# file_get_contents behind a proxy (using proxy list)

Tags: php, proxy, file-get-contents

I use this solution:

```
$aContext = array(
    'http' => array(
        'proxy' => 'tcp://192.168.0.2:3128',
        'request_fulluri' => true,
    ),
);
$cxContext = stream_context_create($aContext);

$sFile = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com", False, $cxContext);

echo $sFile;
```

How do I change the script so that instead of a proxy was used a proxy list in format:

```
...
192.168.0.2:3128
193.123.8.2:3128
194.115.10.2:80
195.178.0.2:80
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, you've got most of the code already, here's what I'd do:

```
<?php
    $proxies = array( '192.168.0.2:3128', '192.168.8.2:3128', '192.168.10.2:80' );

    // Pick a random proxy:
    $proxy_to_use = $proxies[ rand( 0, count( $proxies ) - 1 ) ];

    $aContext = array(
      'http' => array(
        'proxy' => 'tcp://' . $proxy_to_use,
        'request_fulluri' => true,
      ),
    );

    $cxContext = stream_context_create($aContext);
    $content = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com", false, $cxContext);

    echo $content;
?>
```

Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: It was necessary to explain better. I meant no accidental/random use. If a proxy does not work, you should use the following one. If 192.168.0.2:3128' does not work, then repit with '192.168.8.2:3128'...